# Has Superman ever been stabbed with a kryptonite knife?

Tags: dc, superman

In the **comics or DCAU**, have we ever seen Superman stabbed with a kryptonite knife?

I've seen [Metallo](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Metallo) shoot him with a kryptonite bullet, but I don't think I've ever seen anyone attack him with a kryptonite knife.

*I think it might happen in Smallville, but I'm not interested in that*.

Comment: I believe the novelization of *The Death and Life of Superman* mentions that Luthor had paid Deadshot to shoot Superman with a kryptonite bullet at one point.  I don't have my copy on-hand to reference, though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*[Superman: War of the Supermen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman:_War_of_the_Supermen)*

> As the series opens on the heels of the conclusion to Last Stand of New Krypton, Superman is furious that General Zod is moving forward with his plans to make war with Earth. He punches his way into Zod's underground military installation and confronts him. Superman declares his intent to shut down Zod and his war machine. He punctuates his remarks by landing a hard right fist to Zod's jaw.
>
> Rather than retaliate personally, Zod has his minions, Ursa and Non, do his dirty work. **Ursa attacks Superman with a Kryptonite knife**, which draws blood. Superman damages the knife with his heat vision, but does not completely destroy it. Then Non attacks from above, descending feet first and landing hard on Superman. Non and Ursa restrain Superman while Zod gloats.

[image]

Comment: I think this picture [link](http://www.comicvine.com/forums/battles-7/superman-vs-mongul-zod-and-ultraman-1571563/?page=1) might work. At a work computer so sites of this nature are blocked.

Comment: Great find, thanks a lot!

Comment: Technically speaking, more of a slash than a stab, but close enough, eh? :)

Answer (score 4):

In ***Superman Returns***, Lex Luthor stabs Superman in the back with kryptonite. Superman then falls into the ocean with the shard through his chest.

The stabbing:

[image: Lex Stabbing Superman]

Comment: He's specifically asking about "comics or DCAU", not the movies. But otherwise, it's a good answer. :)

Comment: @Ken, you're right. My Google-fu for the stab wound failed me. I'll find a correct image

Comment: I tried to emphasise **comics or DCAU**.

Comment: @InguShama I don't care about SR or smallville also. <grin>

Comment: As a life-long superman fan, I deny the existence of Superman Returns.  Meaning this answer is completely made up :P

Comment: @WizardKnight I hear a lot of people say how they hated the movie, but I've never really heard an explanation for why.  Personally, I enjoyed it, and I thought Kevin Spacey made an absolutely *chilling* Lex Luthor.  What's with all the hate for *Superman Returns*?

Comment: @MasonWheeler I'll give you my top 2 reasons... 1. the movie is supposed to take place 7 years after superman 2, yet all of the actors look like the would have been in middle school 7 years ago.  2. That's superman's kid???  He's not human!  how would him and lois produce offspring?  That's like a Lioness having the cubs of a blue whale

Comment: @WizardKnight [Half-human hybrids](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HalfHumanHybrid) are a time-honored trope in sci-fi and fantasy.  If you can accept [fully human-looking aliens](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HumanAliens) without violating suspension of disbelief, why is it somehow unbelievable that they could have kids?

Comment: @MasonWheeler I can buy into aliens looking like us on the outside, because that's just looks, but once you start messing with the genetics of it, I start getting picky.  Also, DC isn't big on that. In main canon, I can only name 1 or 2 hybrids that weren't created in a lab.

Comment: @WizardKnight: http://joyreactor.com/post/1658983

Answer (score 1):

An almost example from the DCAU:

In the finale to Justice League Unlimited and the DCAU as a whole, "Destroyer", Darkseid immobilises Superman with the "Agony Matrix" and pulls out the hilt of what is either a retractable knife with kryptonite blade or a lightsaber toasting knife. (See: Hitchhiker's Guide, Futurama, etc. :P)

He threatens to carve out Superman's heart but is interrupted by Lex Luthor before he can.

The blade is never explicitly identified as being made of kryptonite, nor is Superman actually stabbed... So what I'm saying is that this is a terrible answer. However, it's green and glowy, and made to kill Superman, so you figure it out.

Comment: So he's threatened with a _possibly_ kryptonite blade? This should really be a comment

Comment: @Daft Great, just give me 50 reputation and I'll oblige.

Comment: Alas... there are trolls everywhere on the interweb.

Comment: I'm being unnecessarily snarky. What I meant to say is that this is the closest example from the DCAU. There doesn't appear to be an official source, but all the wiki's refer to the weapon as a kryptonite knife.