# Can only one organ of Superman be made weak using Kryptonite or Red Sun rays?

Tags: dc, superman

I stumbled upon this fan-made image:

[image: Urinals of Justice League]

It got me wondering if Superman's urinal would really work. Can only one organ of Superman be made weak using Kryptonite or Red Sun rays? Only canonical answer please.

Comment: I can't even....

Comment: Maybe if you removed the cod-piece from this http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Kryptonite-Suit

Comment: @Langshanks But, the question is: Would exposing only one organ of Superman to harmful radiation weaken whole Superman or only that organ?

Comment: Given the characters included, and the look of the art, this would presumably be discussing the Justice League when they operated out of a cave in Happy Harbor, in the 1960s. Do you want information based on the silver-age Superman, or the present-day Superman?

Comment: Why would Superman need to be weakened at all just to pee? I mean, are his molecules so tightly packed that they block the flow otherwise?

Comment: @RemyLebeau The assumption here is that his pee would break the ordinary urinals..

Comment: @CaptainMarvel - I see no reason to assume that.

Comment: @Adamant If in emotional state his hand can accidentally break a strong photo frame, why can't his strong pelvic muscle shoot the pee with strong force?

Comment: @CaptainMarvel - I think you answered your question with the fourth and fifth words of your comment. That only happens when Superman loses control, which doesn't happen very often at all.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know that we have enough source material to definitively answer, because the broader question of [can Superman be weakened by red light](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/183529/have-any-superman-stories-dealt-with-his-weakness-to-red-solar-energy-through-re) is kinda vague. Other than [War of the Supermen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman:_War_of_the_Supermen) and [one DCAU entry](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/Solar_Power) that's pretty much it, and both involved totally blotting out the yellow sun so only the red remained.

My general thought here is that the answer would be "No". Every time this has happened (either total sun blockage or red-only), it resulted in Superman losing all his powers. So it's more of an all-or-nothing way to get at him.

If you want to damage just one organ, your best bet would be a [Kryptonite knife](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102286/has-superman-ever-been-stabbed-with-a-kryptonite-knife).

Answer (score 2):

The joke is based on a slightly outdated interpretation of the red sun "weakness". In silver-age stories, exposure to a red sun (or "red sun radiation") would immediately leave Superman no more powerful than a normal human.

Superman absorbs solar energy from our sun, acting as a solar battery.  A red sun does not generate the amount of power that he needs to remain super-powered.

In current continuity, putting Superman under a red sun lamp will not instantly render him unpowered; it will render him unable to replenish his energy. So he'd get progressively weaker as he used his powers, and his energy store.

So if it were a REALLY LONG pee...